# Images in table: How to make Firefox act same like IE

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table, image-scaling

I have a table with a fix height.
In it there are 2 rows with fix height and 2 rows that contain images.
These cells with images should spread evenly over the remaining height.

Safari, Chrome and IE do it like i want it: Table Height is 500px.
Firefox just ignores the fix height of my table and displays the images in their full height!

How to make Firefox act like Internet Explorer?

```css
img {object-fit: cover; height: 100%; width: 100%; }

table {  
  height:500px; width:100%; 
  table-layout: fixed; 
}
td.static { height:20px }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-230-1.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="static">static height</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img  src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-230-1.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="static">static height</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: This is how Chrome is displaying it]

[image: This is how Firefox is displaying it]

Comment: Can you post screenshots of both results?

Comment: it's not good to write in-line css 
and use firefox prefixed with -moz-

Comment: The code breaks Chrome

Comment: And it seems object-fit is not supported by IE so I am not sure what you are trying and seeing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: Who still uses IE?

Comment: @pol millions of corporate users.

Answer (score 0):

This does not break Chrome. Inline style on the table tag did

```css
img {object-fit: cover; height: 100%; width: 100%; }

table {  
  height:500px; width:100%; 
  table-layout: fixed; 
}
td.static { height:20px }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-230-1.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="static">static height</td>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img  src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-230-1.jpg">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="static">static height</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you i correct this. But this does not solve the problem. Just watch this sample in Chrome and in Firefox

Comment: If the CSS is not supported by IE, then IE is not doing what you expect. If FX and Chrome IS reacting to the CSS, then the difference is between a browser that does NOT do what you ask it to do and ones that DO

Comment: But IE, Safari and Chrome display it in the same way. Firefox instead ignores the height of the table and sizes the images in their full height.
I need to know how to make firefox display that in the same way

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the image as background:

```css
/*img {object-fit: cover; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
*/
td:not(.static) {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-230-1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
table {  
  height:500px; width:100%; 
  table-layout: fixed; 
}
td.static { height:20px }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!--<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-230-1.jpg">-->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="static">static height</td>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!--<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-230-1.jpg">-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="static">static height</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/L03jppr6](https://jsfiddle.net/L03jppr6/)

---

The problem with firefox is that it expects the parent element to have some size defined (if you don't set it, it is assumed `auto`, and it will expand), so just add some `height` to it:

I suggest using variables for this, it will make future edits a lot easier, since you only have to change it in one place.

```css
img {object-fit: cover; height: 100%; width: 100%; }

:root {
--staticTDs: 2; /* number of static tds */
}

td.static { height:20px }

td:not(.static) {
  height: calc( (500px - var(--staticTDs) * 20px) / var(--staticTDs) );
  /* (tableHeight - numberofTDs * heightofStaticTDs) / numberofTDs */
}

table {  
  height:500px; width:100%; 
  table-layout: fixed; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-230-1.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="static">static height</td>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-230-1.jpg">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="static">static height</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/L03jppr6/1](https://jsfiddle.net/L03jppr6/1/)

---

Or you can go all the way, and define variables for all elements.

```css
img {object-fit: cover; height: 100%; width: 100%; }

:root {
--staticTDs: 2; /* number of static tds */
--staticTDheight: 20px; /* height of static tds */
--tableHeight: 500px; /* height of table */
}

td.static { height: var(--staticTDheight) }

td:not(.static) {
  height: calc( (var(--tableHeight) - var(--staticTDs) * var(--staticTDheight)) / var(--staticTDs) );
  /* (tableHeight - numberofTDs * heightofStaticTDs) / numberofTDs */
}

table {  
  height: var(--tableHeight); width:100%; 
  table-layout: fixed; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-230-1.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="static">static height</td>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-230-1.jpg">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="static">static height</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: nice idea but i need these img tags

Comment: Why do you need the img tags? Anyway, the problem on firefox is that `object-fit` expects the parent element to have size defined. So just add some to it. I've edited the answer.